# Кодировка БД MySql

Tags: java, mysql

Есть сервер ява. Использую mysql. так вот в нем не держатся русские символы (вместо них вопросы). Так вот два вапроса:

1. Какая кодировка будет поддерживать Русские, Английские и Туркменские буквы.
2. Как это реализовать? Даже не имею представленин что нужно ввести в консоль чтобы поменять кодировку

Comment: Кодировка UTF-8 наше все

Comment: @Barmaley пробовал переобразовавать в utf8 general ci

Comment: вопрос закрыт. Дела не в базе данных